# hive create map or key/value pair from two arrays

Tags: arrays, hadoop, dictionary, hive, key-value

I have two arrays with same number of values which maps 1:1. I need to create a key/value pair or map(key,value) from those two arrays. Any ideas or tips would be helpful.

Current table structure:

```
USA WEST [NUMBER,Street,City] [135,Pacific,Irvine] 
USA WEST [NUMBER,Street,City] [1672,Madison,Denver]
```

Expected table structure:

```
USA WEST [NUMBER:135,Street:Pacific,City:Irvine] 
USA WEST [NUMBER:1672,Street:Madison,City:Denver]
```

Thank you

Comment: Always 3 elements? Always [NUMBER,Street,City]?

Comment: the number of elements keeps changing based on different messages.

Comment: Add columns names to your post

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to create a delimited string from both arrays, e.g., `NUMBER%Street%City%135%Pacific%Irvine%` and then use regex to replace each token (e.g. `Street`), with itself and the 3rd token to its right (`Pacific`)

#### Demo

(The WITH clause is just for the demo)

Assuming the characters `%` and `&` don't appear in the text

```
with    t as 
        (
            select  stack
                    (
                        2
                       ,'USA WEST',array('NUMBER','Street','City'),array('135','Pacific','Irvine')
                       ,'USA WEST',array('NUMBER','Street','City'),array('1672','Madison','Denver')
                    ) as (c1,a1,a2)
        )
        
select  c1
       ,str_to_map
        (
            substring_index
            (
                regexp_replace
                (
                    concat_ws('%',a1,a2,'')
                   ,'(?<e1>.*?)%(?=((?<e2>.*?)%){3})'
                   ,'${e1}%${e2}&'
                )
               ,'&'
               ,size(a1)
            )
           ,'&'
           ,'%'
        )   as `map`

from    t
;
```

---

```
+----------+------------------------------------------------------+
|    c1    |                         map                          |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------+
| USA WEST | {"NUMBER":"135","Street":"Pacific","City":"Irvine"}  |
| USA WEST | {"NUMBER":"1672","Street":"Madison","City":"Denver"} |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Same thing using the characters with ascii values 1 and 2.

```
with    t as 
        (
            select  stack
                    (
                        2
                       ,'USA WEST',array('NUMBER','Street','City'),array('135','Pacific','Irvine')
                       ,'USA WEST',array('NUMBER','Street','City'),array('1672','Madison','Denver')
                    ) as (c1,a1,a2)
        )
        
select  c1
       ,str_to_map
        (
            substring_index
            (
                regexp_replace
                (
                    concat_ws(string(unhex(1)),a1,a2,'')
                   ,concat('(?<e1>.*?)',string(unhex(1)),'(?=((?<e2>.*?)',string(unhex(1)),'){3})')
                   ,concat('${e1}',string(unhex(1)),'${e2}',string(unhex(2)))
                )
               ,string(unhex(2))
               ,size(a1)
            )
           ,string(unhex(2))
           ,string(unhex(1))
        )   as `map`

from    t
;
```

---

```
+----------+------------------------------------------------------+
|    c1    |                         map                          |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------+
| USA WEST | {"NUMBER":"135","Street":"Pacific","City":"Irvine"}  |
| USA WEST | {"NUMBER":"1672","Street":"Madison","City":"Denver"} |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you first provide the core technical answer before the demo? I am inferring that `strip_to_map(substring_index(regexp_replace(concat_ws(....))))` is the core of it. It's quite a complicated piece of business ..

Comment: @WestCoastProjects, done. Ancient history... :-) No idea why anyone will use Hive these days...

Comment: Bigger companies have plenty of historical hive and actually do new work in it.  IMO it's a v nice tool: handles joins on large tables v well

Comment: There are way better solutions for big data analytics. Check Hive's release notes. The project is barely alive. https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=12346277&styleName=Html&projectId=12310843

Comment: Which solutions do you use?  `Spark` does not handle many of the large table to large table joins as well as `hive`.